javafx tableView data disappear
I encountered a strange bug while using the TableView component in JavaFX. To reproduce this bug, the following conditions need to be met:

The horizontal scrollbar of the TableView needs to appear.
The vertical scrollbar of the TableView needs to appear, but this scrollbar should be non-scrollable.
When you scroll down using the mouse wheel and then click on the table, some data inside the table disappears.

However, I monitored the itemProperty() of the TableView and did not find any changes in the elements.
Environment:

JDK 17
JavaFX 21


package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestTableView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        TableView<Map> tableView = new TableView<>();
        int size = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            TableColumn<Map,String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>(i+"");
            int finalI = i;
            tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map, String> mapStringCellDataFeatures) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(finalI+"");
                }
            });
            tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            tableView.getItems().add(map);
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                map.put(j+"",j+"");
            }

        }
        root.getChildren().add(tableView);
        //Adjust the height according to your screen resolution to reproduce the bug.
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 290);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Popup at Screen Corner");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


Map seems odd here. Could you add more data points to getTableDataFromDBAsListOfList from here and see if you get the same bug?

@SedJ601 This is a simple test case extracted from my actual project. The Map object can be replaced with any other Java object, and the bug can still be reproduced.

Seems like a bug.  You could submit a but report if you wish.

I already report this bug

Comment from a developer on the bug report the Lson created: "The issue is reproducible. I used Win11 x64 machine to reproduce it.
When mouse is scrolled down and the table is clicked, the rows go missing.
It is not reproducible with Java 8 and JFX 11.
Can be reproduced with JFX 20 onwards.".
